# How to redirect .htaccess self-URL to the site index without 403 error?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^error.html$ / [R=301]
```

Everything is working as intended, if I type in a non-existent folder or file I get redirected to the site index.

The problem with accessing .htaccess itself, here is how it works:

```
mysite.com/existing_file.html -> returns file content
mysite.com/non_existing_file.html -> redirects to /
mysite.com/.htwhatever -> redirects to /
mysite.com/.htaccess -> 403 error
mysite.com/.htaccess_non_existent -> 403 error
```

It seems that anything starting from .htaccess returns 403 error

I tried adding

```
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ / [R=301]
```

but it didn't do anything.

Why is it happening and how do I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: But why do you need a fix? Any request starting wtih `/.ht` generates `403` due to some rule in Apache config.

Comment: Because I don't want my site to return 403 errors, I want all 403 errors to be redirected to the index.

Comment: This is what @anubhava is referring to, https://gist.github.com/TheSunMan/4008088#file-httpd-conf-default-L263 - requests for files matching `.ht*` get blocked by default. I am not sure if this can be overwritten later on, or whether you would have to modify this part of the central configuration directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change this behaviour then you will have to override `<Files ".ht*">` first and the redirect using a `RewriteRule`:

```sh
# allow requests for .ht* here first
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all granted
</Files>

# redirect to / here
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.ht / [L,R=301,NC]
```